# powershell watch over folder and log changes to windows application log

Tags: windows, powershell, event-log, file-watcher

As the description, I need to write a powershell script that watches over a folder. And when changes have been made(creation of file, delete, modification) I need to get these changes to get to the windows application log.

This is my code:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\delete-file-event"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  


$action = { 
            New-EventLog -LogName Application -source "logs"
            Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "logs" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "nothing in here"
            $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\delete-file-event\log.txt" -value $logline
          }    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

At this moment it will get to the application logs but that's because of 
Code:

```
New-EventLog -LogName Application -source "logs"
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "logs" -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message "nothing in here"
```

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you facing when using the above code?

Comment: When i'm printing the logs to a file it prints our [Date: Created, Deleted or Renamed: and the file that edited]. With the code right now i'm just getting the output of New-EventLog and Write-EventLog so the problem is that I don't get the [Date: Created, Deleted or Renamed: and the file that edited] in the application log, just "logs", "nothing in here"

Comment: @KristofferTorbiörn You aren't even "telling" the Application log anything about dates, paths or change types. Say, for instance... What do you expect to see in the Application event log if you delete a file in the monitored path? And what do you expect to see in the file you call `log.txt`?

Comment: That's my problem i don't know how to get proper logs to the application log with dates paths folder and files. right now I get these logs into log.txt
Logs:

11/24/2016 16:40:14, Created, C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\delete-file-event\log.txt
11/24/2016 16:42:41, Deleted, C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\delete-file-event\test.bat

I want these to get in the application log,

Thanks for supporting me